# Show will not display all my curves over their full domain

Tags: plotting, legending

My `Show` expression showing four curves will not display the all four curves over the full domain requested in the `PlotRange` option.

Image and code below:

[image: Equation, Plot, and Code]

```
ClearAll[Ts, T]
FullSimplify[1/(5 s + 1)/(1 + Kc/(5 s + 1))]

Ts[Kc_, s_] := 1/(Kc + 1 + 5 s) 10/s;
T[Kc_, t_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[Ts[Kc, s], s, t]
T[Kc, t]

t0 = 30;

Show[
  Plot[T[0.1, t], {t, 0, t0}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> "Kc=0.1"],
  Plot[T[1, t], {t, 0, t0}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLegends -> "Kc=1"],
  Plot[T[2, t], {t, 0, t0}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotLegends -> "Kc=2"],
  Plot[T[10, t], {t, 0, t0}, PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotLegends -> "Kc=10"],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 10}}]

T[0.1, 2]
N[T[1, 2]]
N[T[2, 2]]
N[T[10, 2]]
```

I evaluated `T` at points not shown on the plot to make sure the it is continuous there.

Side note: I cannot get my legend to display color keys (even when using `LineLegends`. Less important than my main issue, but any help with that would be great.

Comment: Adding `, PlotRange -> All` to each call to `Plot` also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) command instead of using [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) to combine multiple plots:

```
Plot[
    {T[.1,t],T[1,t],T[2,t],T[10,t]},
    {t,0,10},
    PlotLegends->{"Kc=0.1","Kc=1","Kc=2","Kc=10"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: An elegant and effective solution, thanks for helping me improve!